# Scraping google news

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, cheerio

i m trying to scrape google news but  something wrong with the code i m using :

```
 var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var path = require('path');
var fs =require('fs');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;


 // Define the requests url

 var url = "https://news.google.com/news";

request(url,function(err,res,body){

var news=[];
 var $page = cheerio.load(body);

var $url=$page('table[class="esc-layout-table"]').find('tbody > tr > td > div > h2 > a').each(function (index, element) {
  news.push($page(element).attr('href'));
});
news={
//desc:$desc,
    url:$url,
//    img:$img,
};



console.log ('success ....'news);



});
```

i would like to have the link to articles and title as well as the thumbnails. that i would store in a firebase database 
but unfortunately i got lost in the rest i console log 
i cant get the result i expect instead i get this in the console :

```
    success .... { '0':
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'a',
     attribs:
      { target: '_blank',
        class: 'article usg-AFQjCNFxodYTzKo8-hM57511iQgBdfn8xA did-3230940966728164415',
        href: 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2016/12/15/jurors-begin-deliberating-in-charleston-church-shooting-trial/',
        url: 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2016/12/15/jurors-begin-deliberating-in-charleston-church-shooting-trial/',
        id: 'MAA4AEgAUABgAWoCdXM',
        ssid: 'h' },
     children: [ [Object] ],
     next: null,
     prev: null,
     parent:
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'h2',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: [Object] } },
  '1':
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'a',
     attribs:
      { target: '_blank',
        class: 'article usg-AFQjCNEQY4otecPJJevDyoBp3K-IQnes2w did-141563424311867977',
        href: 'http://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-will-fact-check-label-fake-news-in-news-feed-2016-12',
        url: 'http://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-will-fact-check-label-fake-news-in-news-feed-2016-12',
        id: 'MAA4AEgBUABgAWoCdXM',
        ssid: 'h' },
     children: [ [Object] ],
     next: null,
     prev: null,
     parent:
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'h2',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: [Object] } },
  '2':
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'a',
     attribs:
      { target: '_blank',
        class: 'article usg-AFQjCNHyGG4zl4RW-AoIILTssJX_TKCybg did--2293954291931624250',
        href: 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-38329461',
        url: 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-38329461',
        id: 'MAA4AEgCUABgAWoCdXM',
        ssid: 'h' },
     children: [ [Object] ],
     next: null,
     prev: null,
     parent:
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'h2',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: [Object] } },
  '3':
```

Note: this is only few of the result if you run the code you will see clearly what i mean 
thanks for advice guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want but try this I got all the url like you want

```
 var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var path = require('path');
var fs =require('fs');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;


 // Define the requests url

 var url = "https://news.google.com/news";

request(url,function(err,res,body){

var news=[];

var $= cheerio.load(body);

$('table[class="esc-layout-table"]').each(function () {
  var image = $(this).find('tbody > tr > .esc-layout-thumbnail-cell > .esc-thumbnail-wrapper > .esc-thumbnail-state > .esc-thumbnail > a > .esc-thumbnail-image-wrapper > img').attr('src');
  var title = $(this).find('tbody > tr > .esc-layout-article-cell > .esc-lead-article-title-wrapper > .esc-lead-article-title > a > span').text();
  var url = $(this).find('tbody > tr > .esc-layout-article-cell > .esc-lead-article-title-wrapper > .esc-lead-article-title > a').attr('href');
  news.push({ url, title, image });
});


console.log ('success ....', news);



});
```

The result

```
success .... [ { url: 'http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/saskatchewan/prisoner-killed-sask-penitentiary-1.3898175',
    title: '1 dead, at least 8 injured in Saskatchewan prison riot',
    image: '//t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKhvczSgL4g3dO8EHkruAEB5AoqkI-PvbB8LzlHBZTPGJYh4bEooNKApDXqTzboNrLpqv3H7MG' },
  { url: 'http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/aleppo-convoy-evacuation-1.3895602',
    title: '3000 people evacuated from eastern Aleppo so far as fragile ceasefire holds',
    image: '//t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ86WfdQJVFE4GrQvu_CPrjx3sqhqut0gjBRv6opfVA4JLIqsWeBDjRWURFGd7h_XN_0D0DnoQ5' },
  { url: 'http://www.cp24.com/news/five-family-members-dead-following-first-nation-fire-1.3204960',
    title: 'Five family members dead following First Nation fire',
    image: '//t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6DkmtVrLs4wzVLDfNZvfOm9Js6rXvSg8ttjdoofJwWUZkM2wSjvLA-HpVZdTJN7pG-1FubXI' },
  { url: 'http://www.ctvnews.ca/business/b-c-offers-five-year-interest-free-down-payment-loans-to-first-time-buyers-1.3205119',
    title: 'BC offers five-year, interest-free down-payment loans to first-time buyers',
    image: '//t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2gUEW4E0gtt5Sj-jFIJP0iC1JIIZ3qi5RbpbwD7otN7B5nKf8qXT-Q1Aaxcs5Z7FVn-LhNXU5' },
```

Hope that can help you :)

Comment: THANK YOU very much , i appreciate the help thanks a lot

Comment: do you know any ressource how i can learn more about cheerio ?! the answer you provide is very good , but i wanst able to figure it out by my self .

Comment: No problem buddy. Watch this video ;) gonna help you ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hptFDG2zmVY

Answer (score 1):

In addition to EQuimper's answer, here's how you can extract data from Google Organic News results. [Full code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-News-Tab-scrape-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js)

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const searchString = "elon musk";                   // what we want to search
const encodedString = encodeURI(searchString);      // what we want to search for in URI encoding

const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
    headers: {
        "User-Agent":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36",
    },                                                  // adding the User-Agent header as one way to prevent the request from being blocked
    params: {
        q: encodedString,                               // our encoded search string        
        tbm: "nws",                                     // parameter defines the type of search you want to do ("nws" means news)
        hl: 'en',                                       // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
        gl: 'us'                                        // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
    },
};

function getNewsInfo() {
    return axios
        .get(`http://google.com/search`, AXIOS_OPTIONS)
        .then(function ({ data }) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(data);

            const pattern = /s='(?<img>[^']+)';\w+\s\w+=\['(?<id>\w+_\d+)'];/gm; //https://regex101.com/r/pMd0yx/1
            const images = [...data.matchAll(pattern)].map(({ groups }) => ({ id: groups.id, img: groups.img.replace('\\x3d', '') }))

            const allNewsInfo = Array.from($('.WlydOe')).map((el) => {
                return {
                    link: $(el).attr('href'),
                    source: $(el).find('.CEMjEf span').text().trim(),
                    title: $(el).find('.mCBkyc').text().trim().replace('\n', ''),
                    snippet: $(el).find('.GI74Re').text().trim().replace('\n', ''),
                    image: images.find(({ id, img }) => id === $(el).find('.uhHOwf img').attr('id'))?.img || "No image",
                    date: $(el).find('.ZE0LJd span').text().trim(),
                }
            });

            return allNewsInfo;
        });
}

getNewsInfo().then(console.log);
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
      "link":"https://www.newyorker.com/news/q-and-a/why-elon-musk-bought-twitter",
      "source":"The New Yorker",
      "title":"Why Elon Musk Bought Twitter",
      "snippet":"Portrait of Elon Musk looking off to the side. Musk, the C.E.O. of Tesla, has previously had some run-ins with the S.E.C.Source photograph by...",
      "image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "date":"2 weeks ago"
   }, ... other results
]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Google News Result API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. SerpApi is a free API with 100 searches per month to test out. If you need more searches, there are paid plans.

The difference is that all that needs to be done is to iterate over a structured JSON instead of coding everything from scratch, maintaining, selecting correct selectors to extract the right data, and figuring out how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

Example code to integrate:

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(API_KEY);        //your API key from serpapi.com

const searchString = "elon musk";                        // what we want to search

const params = {
  engine: "google",                                     // search engine
  q: searchString,                                      // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",                          // google domain: google.com, google.de, google.fr
  gl: "us",                                             // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                                             // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
  tbm: "nws"                                            // parameter defines the type of search you want to do ("nws" means news)
};

const getNewsData = function ({ news_results }) {
  return news_results.map((result) => {
    const { link, title, source, date, snippet, thumbnail: image = "No image" } = result;
    return {
      link,
      source,
      title: title.replace('\n', ''),
      snippet: snippet.replace('\n', ''),
      image,
      date,
    }
  })
};

const getJson = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  })
}

getJson(params).then(getNewsData).then(console.log)
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
      "link":"https://nypost.com/2022/05/13/elon-musk-backs-gop-bid-to-strip-disney-of-mickey-mouse-copyright/",
      "source":"New York Post",
      "title":"Elon Musk backs GOP bid to strip Disney of Mickey Mouse copyright",
      "snippet":"Elon Musk appeared to voice his support for a Republican senator's efforts \n""+""to strip The Walt Disney Co. of its copyright of Mickey Mouse.",
      "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/627e67d93c3fb22215607d9e/images/22b0f5e214e9045c6dc1c6c683cc0b1468248a0cb118e82ed3c7f8900a359195.jpeg",
      "date":"17 mins ago"
   }, ... other results
]
```

If you want to read more about scraping Google, you can check my blog post [How to scrape Google News with Node.js](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-scrape-google-news-with-node-js/)

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi